# Control formatting of a Text element in a plot?

Tags: plotting, labeling

Is it possible to define the format for a part of `Text` in a plot? For instance, is it possible to have `v` bold and `(a)` italic:

```
Show[Graphics3D[Line[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}}]],
 Graphics3D[Text["v(a)", {1.1, 1.1, 1.1}, BaseStyle -> Large]],
 PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {0, 2}, {0, 2}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `Row` and `Style` within a `Text` element, you can get almost any formatting you want.

```
Show[
  Graphics3D[Line[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}}]], 
  Graphics3D[Text[Row[{Style["V", 24, Bold], Style["(a)", 24, Italic]}], {1.1, 1.1, 1.1}]], 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {0, 2}, {0, 2}}]
```

[image]